# When i add figure element to html. I get error

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i dont put figure element in html, everything works perfectly but when i add figure element in html. It doesnt work. I am new to this,can you please help me out here, this thing is bugging my head.

```html
<div class="recipe">
  <div class="message">
    <div>
      <svg>
        <use href="src/img/icons.svg#icon-smile"></use>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <p>Start by searching for a recipe or an ingredient. Have fun!</p>
  </div>

  <figure class="recipe__fig">`
    <img src="src/img/test-1.jpg" alt="Tomato" class="recipe__img" />
    <h1 class="recipe__title">
      <span>Pasta with tomato cream sauce</span>
    </h1>
  </figure>`

 <div class="recipe__details">
    <div class="recipe__info">
      <svg class="recipe__info-icon">
        <use href="src/img/icons.svg#icon-clock"></use>
      </svg>
      <span class="recipe__info-data recipe__info-data--minutes">45</span>
      <span class="recipe__info-text">minutes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe__info">
      <svg class="recipe__info-icon">
        <use href="src/img/icons.svg#icon-users"></use>
      </svg>
      <span class="recipe__info-data recipe__info-data--people">4</span>
      <span class="recipe__info-text">servings</span>

      <div class="recipe__info-buttons">
        <button class="btn--tiny btn--increase-servings">
          <svg>
            <use href="src/img/icons.svg#icon-minus-circle"></use>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <button class="btn--tiny btn--increase-servings">
          <svg>
            <use href="src/img/icons.svg#icon-plus-circle"></use>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What error?  What exactly "doesn't work"?  In what way does the rendered result of this HTML differ from what you expect?

Comment: Your `<div>` and `</div` are not matching. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

Comment: You have an extra backtick after `<figure>` and `</figure>`. I don't think that should cause a problem, but it's probably not wanted.

Comment: When i dont include figure element in the html , html code renders on website perfectly but i add figure element , it says build error in webpage. I am using babel and sass.Any idea why this is happening even though html syntax is correct or it is not?

Comment: @Barmar that is copy error . Also there is no back tick in my code

Comment: Looks like it could be an issue with an addon.

Comment: @kafka007: *"it says build error in webpage. I am using babel and sass"* - Please include information about the problem in the question.